# Problems with login function: my $_POST is not behaving as it should, cannot assign variables with user input

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a simple login function with PHP. The user enters the username and password, and I am using the POST method. But I'm having trouble reading the content of $_POST in order to verify the information the user submitted.

Here is my code:

```
$inp = file_get_contents('php://input');
$_POST = $inp;

if(isset($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]))
{
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
}
```

But username and password never get assigned. 
And additionally, regarding the first two lines:

```
$inp = file_get_contents('php://input');
$_POST = $inp;
```

I was forced to add these later, because without them $_POST is empty. Why is POST empty? Could it have something to do with a faulty html bit?

Here is the HTML Code that takes the input:

```
<form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="login.php">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please Login</h2>

       <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
       <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>

       <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
       <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

      <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

`vardump($_POST);` gives me: `string(34) "username=admin&password=pw"`

`print_r($POST);` gives me `username=admin&password=pw`

I'm completely lost. Would appreciate your input.

Comment: @Jay, that's what I do. See the last lines of my post above, vardump gives me "string(34) "username=admin&password=pw" " 
and print_r gives me just "username=admin&password=pw" :(

Comment: your code works just fine without the $inp = file_get_contents('php://input');
$_POST = $inp; , i've tried it.

Comment: OK - then something is misconfigured in your web server.

Comment: With and without those first two lines, when I try to echo $username after setting it, I get the error: Notice: Undefined variable: username in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dsl/login.php on line 55

Comment: Is that all of the code in your PHP file? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: `$inp` is a string, `$_POST` is supposed to contain an associative array. It's automatically filled in from the `POST` variables in the form, you don't need to assign it yourself.

Comment: The only time you need to use `php://input` is if you're posting data in some format other than URL-encoded or `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Is this the only page that has problems with `$_POST` not getting filled in?

Comment: Check your `php.ini` and make sure it has `variables_order = "GPCS"`. If `P` is missing it won't fill in `$_POST` automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [file_get_contents()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_get_contents.asp) returns a string, to test this use [is_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php), turn the string into array by using [parse_str()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_parse_str.asp) or remove the `file_get_contents()` completely.

```
<?php

$inp = file_get_contents('php://input');
parse_str($inp, $login);

if (isset($login["username"], $login["password"])) {
    $username = $login["username"];
    $password = $login["password"];
}
```

Comment: `explode` won't create an associative array. You need to use `parse_str()`

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use `parse_str` on user input without assigning it to an array. This will allow the client to set arbitrary PHP variables.

Comment: @Barmar thanks noted, OP can use `$_POST` without any problems.

Comment: The whole problem he's having is that he *can't* use `$_POST` for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.

1. I'd try and figure out what problems you're having with $_POST in the first place.
2. Other than that, I'd just parse the string "username=admin&password=pw"

   ```
   $str = "username=admin&password=pw";
   parse_str($str, $output);
   print_r($output);

   # Array
   # (
   #     [username] => admin
   #     [password] => pw
   # )
   ```

Solution from:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any reason why `$_POST` isn't being filled in automatically. But if you want to do it yourself, you need to parse `php://input` into an associative array. The `parse_str()` function does this.

```
$inp = file_get_contents('php://input');
parse_str($inp, $_POST);
```

Maybe the reason `$_POST` isn't being filled in is a problem in your `php.ini`. It should have:

```
variables_order = "GPCS"
```

This tells it to fill in `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`, and `$_SERVER` automatically. If `P` is missing then it won't fill in `$_POST`.

Comment: This won't work, `$_POST` will be empty. `parse_str` returns void.

Comment: @julekgwa Thanks, fixed it.